# MinMax scaling on numpy array multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, normalization

How to minmax normalize in the most efficient way, a XD-numpy array in "columns" of each 2D matrix of the array.

For example with a 3D-array :

```
a = np.array([[[  0,  10],
        [ 20,  30]],

       [[ 40,  50],
        [ 60,  70]],

       [[ 80,  90],
        [100, 110]]])
```

into the normalized array :

```
b = np.array([[[0., 0.],
      [1., 1.]],
     [[0., 0.],
      [1., 1.]],
     [[0., 0.],
      [1., 1.]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn-preprocessing-minmax-scale) + [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis)  single applying:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

a = np.array([[[0, 10], [20, 30]], [[40, 50], [60, 70]], [[80, 90], [100, 110]]])
a_scaled = np.apply_along_axis(minmax_scale, 1, a)
```

---

```
# a_scaled
[[[0. 0.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0.]
  [1. 1.]]]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This solve my problem and is scalable.

Answer (score 2):

```
a_min = a.min(axis=-2, keepdims=True)
a_max = a.max(axis=-2, keepdims=True)
out = (a - a_min) / (a_max - a_min)
```

out:

```
array([[[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: I would add very small value to 'a_max - a_min' in case the evaluated column is like a constant vector. This would help to avoid division by zero. For ex: 'a_max - a_min + 1e-9'. The user also need to store the min and max values if they want to rescale the matrix

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting and simple list comprehension

```
f= lambda ar:(ar==ar.max(axis=0)[None,:]).astype(int)
b = np.array([f(x) for x in a], dtype=float)
print(b)
```

This can also be done using `numpy.apply_along_axis` as follows:

```
ar = np.array([[[0, 10], [20, 30]], [[40, 50], [60, 70]], [[80, 90], [100, 110]]])

def f(a):
   a = a.reshape(2,2)
   return (a==a.max(axis=0)[None,:]).astype(int)

ar = ar.reshape(3,4)
b = np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, ar)
```

output

```
array([[[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Many thanks, useful example of a lambda function applied to an array.